# Can I make Windows 7 Start Menu search show items in order of most frequently used?

Tags: start-menu, windows-search

I work as a web applications developer; during the course of a day I open applications a *lot*.

The search box in the start menu that appeared in Vista & 7 has been a godsend.  Hit the start key, type a few letters, enter, bam - application launched.  Much faster than navigating my often enormous start menu with a mouse.

But, lately, I notice the application I want is often not first in the search results.

Take this example:

[image: picture of searching "sql"]

When I type `sql` into the search box, it appears to sort the results alphabetically - but 95% of the time I want to open SQL Server Management Studio.  It is an order of magnitude slower to open the application when it is not the first item in the list.

**Is there any way to affect the order of search results here?**

Preferably, it would use a most frequently used algorithm to prioritize items I select more often, but if I can influence it in any way I would like to know.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem but made a work around.

```
Rename the start menu item.
Add a symbol such as "~" in the front of the shortcut name.

~SQL Server Management Studio
```

Type "sql" and the renamed item will always be on top.

Answer (score 1):

I'm, sadly, not aware of a method to change the order of the search results. But I found it helpful to include wildcards in my searches in those situations.
For example

```
m*v*s
```

Would bring me right to

```
Microsoft Visual Studio
```

Maybe that helps :)